# The alignment of formatting string and number

Tags: python

Upon reviewing the [string — Common string operations — Python 3.7.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)

The default left alignment or right alignment confused me,

As for number, the default is left alignment as C's print

```
In [9]: !printf '%10d' 42
        42
In [10]:  '{:10d}'.format(42)
Out[10]: '        42'
```

When comes with strings

```
In [19]: '%10s' % ('test',)
Out[19]: '      test'

In [20]: !printf '%10s' test
      test
In [21]: '{:10}'.format('test')
Out[21]: 'test         '
```

The default is right alighment which oppsite the number alighment and C's style

What's consideration behind this?

Comment: It is easy to read numbers when they’re all right-aligned as each digit (tenths, units, tens, hundreds, etc.) is in the same column. (Assuming the decimal parts are all rounded to the same accuracy)

Comment: I assumed that their initial consideration of LTR and plan to reduce the cumbersome jobs to input < or >, but final result is they add extra work load, since you have to explicitly declare < left-alighted or > right-aligted